# Reload Localized Layout After Locale Changed in Service

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have a keyboard service which displays a soft keyboard input to the end user. I am planning on expanding this to support multiple languages, though I am running into a problem when attempting to reload the layout file with a new localization.

My problem is that when a configuration change is triggered, the strings update with their new localized version based on the locale, but the layout does not change to reflect the new locale.

For example, I have this bit of code:

```
//Update configuration to reload localization
Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
config.setLocale(locale); //locale is a Locale object for Spanish (Spain)
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
```

This is called from a class which `extends InputMethodService` and `implements OnKeyboardActionListener`

This will trigger a configuration change, and as a result when the keyboard view appears I can see that some of the strings used have changed over to Spanish. However, it seems the layout has not been reloaded.

For reference, I have the following `xml` files:

`layout_qwerty.xml` (some information redacted)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Keyboard>
    <Row>
        <Key/>
...
        <Key/>
    </Row>
</Keyboard>
```

`layout_qwerty.xml (es)` (some information redacted)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Keyboard>
    <Row>
        <Key/> <!-- Some different key here, say ñ -->
...
        <Key/>
    </Row>
</Keyboard>
```

`strings.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="label_enter_key">Enter</string>
</resources>
```

`strings.xml (es)`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="label_enter_key">Intro</string>
</resources>
```

I know that this works in theory because using the default Android `LocalePicker` to change localization updates the keyboard view with the new layout as well as the new strings. It's only when performing the configuration change myself programmatically that I do not see the layout updated, only the strings. Looking in Android source code at what `LocalePicker` does to trigger the configuration change uses hidden classes and functions which are inaccessible from a top level application, so I don't think I am able to do the same. (see [updateConfiguration](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/com/android/internal/app/LocalePicker.java) method for reference)

Here are some images showing the difference between changing locale via application code and changing it via the native Android `LocalePicker`:

Full English (Default state)
[image: Full English (Default state)]

Half Spanish (Locale changed via application code)
[image: Half Spanish (Locale changed via applicatio code); notice that the soft keys are translated but the layout is the same, so there is no ñ key]

Full Spanish (Locale changed via native Android `LocalePicker`)
[image: Full Spanish (Locale changed via native Android <code>LocalePicker</code>); notice we now have the ñ key]

Notice how only in the last image we have the ñ key available, showing that our layout was properly reloaded.

I have tried things like invalidating the view (e.g. `mInputView.invalidate()`) and manually calling `onCreateInputView()` but after redraw the view still showed the old layout.

Is there anything I can do to reload the layout after locale change?